# Register new istioctl profile

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I want to install istio with istioctl. My customizations will be numerous, so I dont think it would be helpful to use this syntax: `istioctl manifest apply --set addonComponents.grafana.enabled=true`

I figured that the best way to do it is to copy a profile from `istio-1.5.1/install/kubernetes/operator/profiles`

How can I add a custom profile to:

```
[root@localhost profiles]# istioctl profile list
Istio configuration profiles:
    remote
    separate
    default
    demo
    empty
    minimal
```

So that I can: `istioctl manifest apply --set profile=mynewprofile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`istio manifests apply --set addonComponents.grafana.enabled=true` would translate to

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  addonComponents:
    grafana:
      enabled: true
```

Istio uses the CR IstioOperator to pass values for installation. All customization options listed [here](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.operator.v1alpha1/) are available. Some examples can  be found in their documentation under [Installation Configuration Profiles](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/istioctl/#configure-component-settings) and within their [releases](https://github.com/istio/istio/releases) under `install/kubernetes/operator/profiles`.

You can make custom profiles by referencing a path to another CR. Let's say you turned the file above into a-new-profile.yaml.

```
istioctl manifest apply --set installPackagePath=< path to istio releases >/istio-1.5.1/install/kubernetes/operator/charts \
    --set profile=path/to/a-new-profile.yaml
```

After that, you would have your new profile set and ready to use. See their section [install-from-external-charts](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/istioctl/#install-from-external-charts) for more information.

Comment: Thanks dude. I something that you said here clarified it for me.

Comment: how about to get the current value like `addonComponents.grafana.enabled`